# working with threads in php

Tags: php, multithreading

I am trying to learn threads in php and trying to execute three threads parallel. and this is my code

```
        $set = "abcacbabccbacab";
    $_set = $set;
    echo "S = {".$_set."}<br/>";
    $rule1 = new Rule1($_set);
     $rule2 = new Rule2($_set);
      $rule3 = new Rule3($_set);
    $_set = $rule1->run();
    $_set = $rule2->run();
    $_set = $rule3->run();
    echo "S` = {".$_set."}<br/><br/>";

class Rule1 extends Thread
{
public function __construct($set)
{
    $this->set = $set;
}
public function run()
{
    $check = false;
        $set = str_replace("abc", "aab", $set);
        $check = true;

    return $set;
}
}

class Rule2 extends Thread
{
public function __construct($set)
{
    $this->set = $set;
}
public function run()
{
    $check = false;
        $set = str_replace("ac", "ba", $set);
        $check = true;

    return $set;
}
}

class Rule3 extends Thread
{
public function __construct($set)
{
    $this->set = $set;
}
public function run()
{
    $check = false;
        $set = str_replace("cb", "cc", $set);
        $check = true;

    return $set;
}
}
```

But, whenever I try to run application it throws me this error

Uncaught Error: Class 'Rule1' not found

Even though the class is present with the name of Rule1 but it still shows.

Comment: You're using the class before initializing it, move it above. https://3v4l.org/mXX9H vs https://3v4l.org/bGAhN

Comment: Why is it saying class thread not found?

Comment: Because 3v4l does not have the pthreads extension..